# LCS using Dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, pseudocode, lcs

I am learning how to solve the longest common subsequence using dynamic programming. I understand how the table works, however, I don't get the reason why the formula for x[i]!=y[j] is like this max{c[i − 1, j], c[i, j − 1]}. Why not other formulas?

Comment: "..other formulas" like?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.